# checking a var for matches against an array

Tags: php, arrays, validation

First off I know this is a duplicate question that is asked on here fairly often, however I have perused through those answers and still can't figure out what is wrong with my code. I am fairly new to PHP, and I am 99% sure this is a very easy/novice thing to accomplish, which is why it's frustrating me.

Here is the code:

```
    $validProgram = 0;
$validProgramCodes = array('ITFZ', 'ITFC', 'ITFP', 'ITFE', 'ITFL', 'ITFS',
                           'ITFF', 'ITFM', 'ITFT', 'IEME', 'ISMK', 'IPKT');

if ( isset( $_GET[ 'category' ] ) && isset( $_GET[ 'subcategory' ] )
    && $_GET[ 'category' ] != '' && $_GET[ 'subcategory' ] != '' )
{
    $selectedSchool = $_GET[ 'category' ];
    $selectedProgram = $_GET[ 'subcategory' ];
    $selectedSchool = prepString( $selectedSchool );
    $selectedProgram = prepString( $selectedProgram );

    foreach ( $validProgramCodes as $temp )
    {
        if ( $temp == $selectedProgram )
        {
            $validProgram ++;
        }
    }

    if ( $validProgram == 1 )
    {
        echo "success!";
    }
    else if ( $validProgram !== 1)
    {
        echo "failure!";
    } 
}
```

}

Now... for some reason, no matter what is supplied for $selectedProgram, the validation check echos out the failurestatement. This is really simple code so I'm sure it's something glaringly obvious, but I think I just need another pair of eyes to give it a quick glance over. :)

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if ( $validProgram = 1 )` *assigns* the value `1` to `$validProgram`. This assignment returns `1`, so the statement always passes.

Try `if ( $validProgram == 1 )` to test for equality.

Regardless, looking at the whole block, it looks like you compress a lot of this down to a single [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) check, removing the `foreach` loop and the `$validProgram` variable entirely:

```
$selectedProgram = prepString( $selectedProgram );

if(in_array($selectedProgram, $validProgramCodes))
{
    echo "success!";
}
else
{
    echo "failure!";
}
```

Comment: Wow, now I feel stupid! I knew it was something little... I just assumed I had used == and my eyes didn't even check. Thanks! However, now everything outputs as invalid... Hmm

Comment: @TomC: rather than debugging the big block in which you check for array membership, maybe using PHP's built-in function will solve your issue. Otherwise, I'd recommend running `var_dump($selectedProgram)` before checking if it's in the array to make sure that the variable actually contains what you expect.

Comment: Hi Matchu, for some reason var_dump is claiming I only have 6 entries in the array, when in fact there are 12... Odd! Excuse my ignorance, but what is the built-in PHP function you are referring to?

Comment: @TomC: edited the answer to point to PHP's built-in [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) function, which checks if a given element appears anywhere in a given array.

Comment: Great! I didn't know about in_array, very handy. I will be using that. :) However it is still echoing "failure" regardless of my selection? Any ideas? (thanks so much for the help by the way! Learning a lot.) **EDIT** Nevermind! The problem was with my prepString function. Doh. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
if ( $validProgram = 1 )
```

It should be:

```
if ( $validProgram == 1 )
```

Otherwise you're always assigning 1 to `$validProgram`, which will return `TRUE`'.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a way using `RegExp`.

```
$codeIsValid = preg_match('/^('.implode('|', $validProgramCodes).')$/i', $programCodeToCheck);

if ($codeIsValid)
  echo 'Valid';
else
  echo 'Not Valid';
```

*Note: case insensitive match possible !*

Or as previously proposed use `in_array()`, but lead the code (*that you will match against valid codes*) to one case.

```
$programCodeToCheck = strtoupper($programCodeToCheck); // leading string to the case that validCodes are
$codeIsValid = in_array($selectedProgram, $validProgramCodes); // testing array for possible match
```